# How to handle to index size error: The index is not in the allowed range?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I get the error in Safari - indexSizeError: The index is not in the allowed range. Could you explain what this error mean and how to handle this? It would be great if somebody provide an example how to solve this. This error appears im my method after the loop

```
for (let index = 0; index < something.length; index++) {
```

How to handle such errors?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 5 elements in array ( or object ? ), something.length returns 5, but index 5 does not exist since arrays (/objects ?) are 0 indexed, i.e from index 0 upto index (something.length - 1).

```
for (let index = 0; index <= (something.length - 1); index++) {
```

[image]

Comment: I think if  When you initialize `index=0` and `(something.length - 1);`  You'll get one element less

Comment: That is the point ! With an array of 5 elements, index 0 is first element, last element is at index 4 ( array.length - 1 ). There are no elements at index 5 !

Comment: Alrigt Consider `var a = [1,2,3,4,5];` `for (let index = 0; index < (a.length - 1); index++) {
console.log(a[i]);
}` Will return `1,2,3,4`

Comment: Yes, in chrome console and php as well. Well, there is a possibility the language you use does not 0 index arrays, but I heavily doubt that.

Comment: @Madhan thanks for pointing this out, I had forgotten to fix the logical comparison.

Comment: `i <= length - 1` is exactly the same as `i < length`. Your code is not different from the question.

Comment: @FacelessPanda the functionality is different. I will try to explain. i.length in javascript will raise an exception since length is not the last index in array. To get last index u need to do i.length - 1. Now "< i.length-1" will NOT go till last index, which is why we use i <= length - 1.

Comment: On the last iteration, when `i` gets incremented to `something.length`, the condition `i < something.length` will resolve to `false`, thus not running the loop once more. As @FacelessPanda mentioned, the code in your answer has the same functionality as the question's code. The code in the question should also not raise an error, given that `something` is a valid array

Comment: It's not. something.length goes upto a non existant index which throws the error